# show specific form in multiform using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using `multiform` for survey project. I am using fieldsets in form to display a single form each time. my problem is that eveything works fine but when user refreshes the page it takes user to the first form which is wrong it should keep user on the current form. I couldn't find the best solution yet the code which I am using is here

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var current = 1,

    steps = $("fieldset").length;
  $(".next").click(function() {

    var form = $("#workbook_form");
    form.validate();
    if (form.valid() == true) {
      // $('.timer').countimer('start');
      current_step = $(this).parent();
      next_step = $(this).parent().next();
      next_step.show();
      current_step.hide();
      setProgressBar(++current);
    }
  });


  $(".previous").click(function() {
    current_step = $(this).parent();
    next_step = $(this).parent().prev();
    next_step.show();
    current_step.hide();

    setProgressBar(--current);
  })
  setProgressBar(current);
  // Change progress bar action
  function setProgressBar(curStep) {
    var percent = parseFloat(100 / steps) * curStep;
    percent = percent.toFixed();
    $(".progress-bar")
      .css("width", percent + "%");
    $(".percent").html(percent + "%");

  }

});
```

```css
#workbook_form fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="workbook_form" name="workbook_form" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-3 mr-2 float-end next " value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: You basically need, at page load, read sessionStorage ( or other storage technology!) to see if the active form has been stored and reload if it has - the `next` and `previous` buttons load whichever form is appropriate and then update your storage technology. As you have shown only a fragment of the HTML/Javascript & css a more precise answer is not possible. I'd suggest though adding a `dataset` attribute to each `form` or `fieldset` (whichever you load each time ) and use that to track progress

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not saving the current form state. True, you have assigned it to a variable, but the variable also reassigns if the user refreshes the website.

Here, a fairly simple approach to save the user state

```js
  const useState = (stateId) => {
            const setState = (newState) => localStorage.setItem('state_' + stateId, newState);
            const getState = () => localStorage.getItem('state_' + stateId)
            return [getState, setState];
        }
```

Here is your code

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            const [state, setState] = useState(1);
            if (state() == null) {
                setState(1);
            }

            steps = $("fieldset").length;
            $(".next").click(function () {

                var form = $("#workbook_form");
                form.validate();
                if (form.valid() == true) {
                    // $('.timer').countimer('start');
                    current_step = $(this).parent();
                    next_step = $(this).parent().next();
                    next_step.show();
                    current_step.hide();
                    setProgressBar(setState(state() ++));
                }
            });


            $(".previous").click(function () {
                current_step = $(this).parent();
                next_step = $(this).parent().prev();
                next_step.show();
                current_step.hide();

                setProgressBar(setState(state() --);
            })
            setProgressBar(state());
            // Change progress bar action
            function setProgressBar(curStep) {
                var percent = parseFloat(100 / steps) * curStep;
                percent = percent.toFixed();
                $(".progress-bar").css("width", percent + "%");
                $(".percent").html(percent + "%");

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

So below I've created an example for simply navigating between `fieldset` groups and restoring the current group on reload. However, there are a number of things to concider:

1. The use of [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to prevent next/prev will cause issues due to it validating the entire form in one go and not by individual `fieldset`.
2. The restoring of field values when the page is reloaded.

For this I've created a custom plugin that handles the show/hiding of fieldsets and can be triggered on load or on click with the below. I took this approach as the main plugin can be somewhat extendable to allow for the addition of field validation and value storing.

**Triggerable events**

```js
// Go to next fieldset (if has one)
$form.trigger( 'next' );

// Go to previous fieldset (if has one)
$form.trigger( 'prev' );

// Go to specific fieldset
const fieldsetIndex = 4;
$form.trigger( 'goto', [ fieldsetIndex ] );
```

**Attachable events**

The plugin also fires an event once the fieldset has changed which we can utilise to store the current fieldset index...

```js
$form.on( 'went', function( event, data ) {
  sessionStorage.setItem( 'fieldsetIndex', data.current );
} );
```

The `data` object passed in the `went` event above includes the following:

```js
/**
 * @var {Number} current The current fieldset index.
 * @var {Number} minIndex The minimum fieldset index.
 * @var {Number} maxIndex The maximum fieldset index.
 * @var {Number} percent The current fieldset percentage.
 * @var {jQuery} $target The current fieldset jQuery object.
 * @var {jQuery} $others All the other (non-active) fieldset jQuery objects.
 */
```

**Code and example**

The code and working example can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/thelevicole/qm7w51h4/

You can also watch a screenrecording of the above example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gdIggGnZ2M